# Can the following equation be written as an exponential equation?

Tags: exponential-function

I have read a sample word equation to represent an exponential function, where I was supposed to identify if this equation was exponential or not. I have determined that it is exponential, but would like to be able to write this as a function. The word equation is a follows: "Every year the number of elk in a country increases by $12\%$ from the previous year." I came up with the function: $n=n_x(.12)+n$", where $n=$ number of Elk, and $n_x=$ the updated number of Elk as the year progresses. I know it's not neat, and I know there is a way better way to write but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the beginning you have $e_0$ elk in country. The next year you will have $e_1=e_0+0.12e_0=1.12e_0$. The next year you will have $e_2=1.12e_1=1.12^2e_0$. In general $e_n=1.12^n e_0$.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks! Any material that you recommend so that I can start seeing & resolving equations in this way?

Comment: Actually, it is not very different than geometric sequences. Are you familiar with this topic?